# Two cones intersect such that the vertex of one coincides with the center of the other's base. Find the volume of their intersection.

Tags: geometry

One cone of radius $4$ and height $12$, and another cone of radius $6$ and height $12$, intersect such that the vertex of one coincides with the center of the base of the other. Find the volume of the intersection of the cones.

Comment: Can you please point a direction of approach you've already tried?

Comment: Hint: it is the sum of two cones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

From similar triangles in the diagram, we have

$$\frac x4=\frac b{12},\>\>\>\>\>\frac x6=\frac a{12}\implies x(\frac14+\frac16) = \frac{a+b}{12}=1$$

which yields $x = \frac {12}5$. Thus, the intersecting volume is

$$\frac13 \cdot 12\cdot (\pi x^2)= \frac{576\pi}{25}$$

Comment: Interestingly enough, $x$ depends not of the common height of the cones, but on their radii solely.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe - but conditional on the two cones having the same height

Comment: Of course, a nice result.